# How to use SonarQube Dependency Check plugin in TFS?

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, tfsbuild, sonarqube-scan, owasp

I've implemented SonarQube and Dependency Check task in TFS with below configuration:

**1. Prepare analysis on SonarQube task**

```
sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=**/*.trx
sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=**/*.coveragexml
sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=$(Build.SourcesDirectory) 
sonar.cfamily.threads=6
sonar.cfamily.cppunit.reportsPath=$(Build.SourcesDirectory) 
sonar.branch.name=$(Build.SourceBranchName)
sonar.dependencyCheck.reportPath=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\dependency-check-report.xml
sonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\dependency-check-report.html
```

**2. OWASP Dependency Check task**

```
C:\tools\dependency-check\bin\dependency-check.bat --project "xyz" -f ALL -s "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)" -o "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
```

but getting an error in this step:

> [ERROR] Unable to download meta file:
>   https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.0/nvdcve-1.0-modified.meta

I have downloaded dependency check command line plugin from https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Dependency_Check

Comment: Does you server has access to [nvd.nist.gov](https://nvd.nist.gov) server?

Comment: Yeah so this one is resolved but getting different error **ERROR BTree structure error LONG_RECORD chain starting at 5925 is too long** on Run Code Analysis step.

Comment: @NaveenKumar Since this issue has been resolved. Suggest you raise a new ticket to track another issue (if it not solved), if already been solved. You could also kindly share the solution here.Which will also helps others in the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this question by myself, please see below

NIST is the government organization which maintains all vulnerability data.
NVD (National Vulnerability Database) is the database from where it fetches the data.

So I was getting this error due to NVD database was down at that moment as many people polls the database at same time.